# Creating a scoring system in binary logistic regression

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, binary-data

I have used forwards binary logistic regression to determine which predictors are significant in classifying patients into two clinical categories. Three significant predictors were identified. Could I create an overall score for each patient based on B value obtained in logistic regression and as follows
Score = B value of predictor 1 (score of predictor1) + B value of predictor 2 (score of predictor 2) + B value of predictor 3 ( score of predictor 3) = overall individual score for that patient.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Do you means that you used stepwise regression for variable selection?

Comment: Since "significant predictors were identified" we already know this is not acceptable statistical practice.